# Gmail API Oauth2 Send from different address

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am able to send e-mails using Python and the google libraries (`googleapiclient`, `google_auth_oauthlib.flow`, and `google.auth.transport.requests`). I'm trying to get an alternate "from" or "reply-to" address, and it's not working. My code for creating a message is like so:

```
# Returns an e-mail message suitable for submission through the gmail api.
def create_message(sender, to, subject, message_text):
    message = MIMEMultipart()
    message['to'] = to
    #message['from'] = sender
    message['from'] = 'derp@nowhere.com'
    message['subject'] = subject
    message.attach(MIMEText(message_text, 'html'))
    return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string().encode()).decode()}
```

As you can see, I've adjusted the `from` attribute of the `message`. When this message is sent, it is from the gmail account owner, not "derp". How do I make the message come from a different address?

Comment: This functionality is working fine using "less secure apps".

Comment: Hello @LimitedAtonement, so you are trying to send an email from another user's e-mail address? If so, it is only normal to get the other account to approve the permissions needed. As for "less secure apps", Google might block anyone who’s trying to sign in to that account, which I wouldn't consider to be a viable option. Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Thank you! The solution we currently have in place uses "less secure apps" and is able to send from any "from" address we can dream up. Now we need to get the other account to approve? That's too bad. I understand E-Mail is an insecure communication medium because e-mails can be spoofed so easily. I guess Google is trying to bring that easy of spoofing to an end single-handedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the e-mail address as whom you want to issue e-mail as a "Send Mail As" account: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/2/#settings/accounts. It is necessary for that other account to verify he has control of that e-mail address.

It appears not to be possible to "spoof" e-mails using gmail oauth without this verification process, though if you use the deprecated "less secure apps", it is still possible.